# More Elegant Way Selecting Bit-size and Pseudo-Random Bit Generation

Tags: c#, random, binary, bit-manipulation

Is there a more elegant way of doing the bit size selection and pseudo-random binary bit generation than I am doing here? Actually I need to write an algorithm where the user is in control of the bit size (max 16 bit) of the random binary bit generated. This is the function I wrote however I am not sure if this is the smallest/most elegant. As this is scientific in need efficiency doesn't matter much but elegance of code and easy understandability does matter. So is there a more efficient/elegant way of doing the same?

```
static string randomBit() {
    int bitSize = 0, input = 0;
    Console.Write("Input Bit Size (Maximum is 16 Bit): ");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Random choice = new Random();
    if(input == 0 || input > 16) {
        bitSize = 0;
    }
    else if(input == 1) {
        bitSize = 1;
    }
    else if(input == 2) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(2, 3);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 3) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(4, 7);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 4) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(8, 15);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 5) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(16, 31);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 6) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(32, 63);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 7) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(64, 127);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 8) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(128, 255);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 9) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(256, 511);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 10) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(512, 1023);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 11) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(1024, 2047);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 12) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(2047, 4095);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 13) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(4096, 8191);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 14) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(8192, 16383);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 15) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(16384, 32767);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    else if(input == 16) {
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(32768, 65535);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }
    string binary = Convert.ToString(bitSize, 2);
    return binary;
}
```

Also as a second question, if I **press Enter twice** when the code is asking for bit size, it **returns an exception error**. Is there a way to bypass the same?

Comment: Why are you insisting on a value of (say) 8 or more if the bit size is 4? You're basically removing one bit of randomness by forcing the most significant bit to be 1. (You should ask your second question *as* a second question, by the way.)

Comment: you can also use Int32.TryParse http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse for second question

Comment: @Jon Skeet I did this assuming 8 - 1000, 9 - 1001, so on. I actually don't know how to implement a function that can fill the previous bits with 0's (that is without going into arrays) depending on the bit size, say 4 bit but the binary number generated is 2 to the output will be 0010. However randomness is of utmost importance. is there another way?

Comment: @Jeet.Deir: A random number of 4 bits should have 16 possible values - 0000 to 1111, with *all* values feasible, not just 1000 to 1111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I really think you can reduce the number of if/else statements:

```
private static string randomBit()
{
    int bitSize = 0, input = 0;
    Console.Write("Input Bit Size (Maximum is 16 Bit): ");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Random choice = new Random();

    if (input <= 0 || input > 16)
    {
        bitSize = 0;
    }
    else if(input == 1)
    {
        bitSize = 1;
    }
    else
    {                        
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(1 << (input-1), (1 << input)-1);
        bitSize = randomChoice;
    }

    string binary = Convert.ToString(bitSize, 2);
    return binary;
}
```

If you're not comfortable with the left shifts in this expression: `int randomChoice = choice.Next(1 << (input-1), (1 << input)-1);` and you're interested more in readability then you could always replace that with:

```
int randomChoice = choice.Next(Math.Pow(2, input - 1), Math.Pow(2, input) - 1);
```

As far as the question regarding the exception, the answer is yes. The problem you have is that you don't validate the input to the `Convert.ToInt32` function.

Instead of `input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` you could write:

```
do
{
   string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
   if(!Int32.TryParse(inputString, out input))     // will return false if it can't convert
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 16!");
       input = 0;
   }
}while(input == 0);
```

Comment: Can you please explain this statement a bit? `else
    {                        
        int randomChoice = choice.Next(1 << (input-1), (1 << input)-1);`

Comment: The left shift operator (`<<`) will shift all bits of the variable on the left, to the left, by as many positions as indicated by the value on the right. In the `1 << input` example, you are essentially moving bit 0 of 0x00000001 to the left _input_ number of positions - which incidentally corresponds to powers of 2. You can look this up further (ask another question) or use the other statement I showed in the answer (see my answer) :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I would really love to learn about the shift operators. Power is what we use, but shifting is something new for me. Should I ask a fresh question? Also, small query, to use the pow function wont I need a double rather than an int?
Thanks.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir - if you found the answer helpful you can always show your appreciation by up-voting/marking as answer ;)  As for Math.Pow - no, the compiler will handle the cast for you. For more info on shift operators, after doing a Google search I recommend asking a fresh question with details of exactly what you'd like to know..

Comment: You were most helpful Miky but I can't up-vote an answer as I have reps < 15 :( . Sorry for that.

Comment: Sure I will. Just a last question. Also what Jon Skeet mentioned, is it possible to implement the same without going into arrays? I actually don't know how to implement a function that can fill the previous bits with 0's (that is without going into arrays) depending on the bit size, say 4 bit but the binary number generated is 2 to the output will be 0010. But randomness is very important to me, so if this means sacrificing on randomness than I should implement an array to fill previous blank bits with 0's, or does the bit shifting implementation you showed does that already?.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir - your last question is not entirely clear to me. Please ask a new question and try to be a bit more clear and I (and others) will be able to better help you get the answers you're looking for. The comments section is not really designed for this..